# deploy java EE application on the server

Tags: java, mysql, angularjs, spring

I have just finished developing a java application angularjs and java EE and mysql and tomcat, spring boot, my manager has just given me a a real server with windows server 2012 and ip@ x.x.x.x to deploy the app inside,but i have never done that before, can anybody please tell the steps to follow to make my application online, and deploy it on the server

Comment: What kind of sdserver do you have? tomcat is not a JavaEE Server, A tomcat has a folder, where you simply put your generated .war-file. The life deployment is exactly like the dev-deploment.

Comment: thank you for your answer, i have tomcat as servlet container,but what i cant figure out is, before deploying my app i have to change mysqk porte in my code and also 8080 porte.??

Comment: mysql port and tomcat ports are different

Comment: i want to my app to use mysql in the server and also i dont want the app to be accissible vie localhost:8080 i want to be accissible via the servers @ip how i can achieve that??

Comment: mysql's default port number is 3306. so if you running mysql on 192.168.1.15 you'll connect to it through 192.168.1.15:3306  you can configure your mysql in the my.cnf file (might be called my.ini for windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**step-1**. here I'm deploying **pos.war** 
First go to tomcat webapps folder and past it

[image]

**step-2.** go to tomcat->bin folder start tomcat by clicking **startup.bat**

**step-3.** go to browser write localhost:port/project name eg. **localhost:8080/pos** (here my tomcat run on port 8080)

Done....

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer thats very useful but, i have to change my mysql port ? i also i dont want the app to be accessible with localhose:8080 i want to be accessible via server @IP x.x.x.x is that possible???

Comment: You need to edit tomcat's server.xml file and change the port number of the http <Connector> from 8080 to 80 and restart Tomcat.

Comment: thank you!!! what about mysql url?? because its hard coded in code, do i have to change it before i generate the war??

Comment: # DataSource settings:
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ctm
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password =
spring.datasource.driverClassName = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
# Specify the DBMS
spring.jpa.database = MYSQL
# Show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create
# Naming strategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

Comment: I don't want to peel banana for anyone else, before ask, try to understand what this means..."jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ctm"

Comment: but as you see the url is hard coded,because logically the URL must be url = jdbc:mysql://@of server:3306/ctm, you agree with me??

Comment: If you replace "@of server" with some IP addess, still it is hardcoded :-). I don't think of a scenario where database server's are dynamically changing.

Comment: look ser, my question is simple, i have to change the mysql url from url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ctm to url = jdbc:mysql://ServerIp@:3306/ctm before i generate the war or not?

Comment: you have to change the url to the location of the mysql. if it is ServerIp@:3306 then yes change it to that